# abholen in, von or aus

Tags: preposition

Which preposition should I use with the verb abholen? I have seen examples with "in (an), aus and von": Ich hole die Kinder aus der Schule ab / Ich hole die Kinder von der Schule ab. But also: Ich hole dich am Bahnhof ab. Are all these sentences correct? Could I say: "Ich hole dich in deiner Wohnung ab" or is it better to say "aus deiner Wohnung"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In former times you might have said 'Confucius says'. In our days replace Confucius by Google:

[image]

> Jemanden *von der Schule* abholen

mostly means *a child after classes*.

> Jemanden *an der Schule* abholen

means: The school (more precisely: *die Straße direkt vor der Schule*) is the place, where you pick up the other person, maybe a pupil, maybe a 'schulfremde Person'.

> Jemanden *aus der Schule* abholen

means: The person enters the school building in order to collect the other person.

> Jemanden *vom Bahnhof* abholen

usually refers to a person coming by train.

As for *jemanden von zu Hause abholen*, I would prefer

> Ich komme zu dir und hole ich da ab.
>
> Ich hole dich von zu Hause ab.

You can also say

> Ich hole dich bei dir zu Hause ab.

One problem of talking of directions is: They are at the same time very 'not standard' and very imprecise. For an exact localization more detailed inquieries are needed. In my experience very many people are incapable to clearly designate a place. As by miracle most appointments 'work' in spite of the vagueness of the meeting place.